# Can you make custom aliases?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to alias / make custom elements behave like others

E.g. `<large>` should work like `<h1>`

Comment: I don't think so. You can orderide the default styles but not just point to another element.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: @LewisMilburn Why you don't you class?

Comment: In the css: http://jsbin.com/gomefo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @marcelo2605 I could but I'm making a 'more basic' form of HTML I've done it before but I forgot how to

Comment: @LewisMilburn How abou web components?

Comment: Thanks mosh! That's exactly what I was on about.

Comment: @marcelo2605 I have no idea what they are, I'm not the best at HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but they reach have their own problems.

1. Using Classes - This would create the same effect, but isn't what you asked for.
2. Assigning default h1 values to large like so:

   large{font-size:32px;}

This isn't a true alias though, since you have to apply your rules for every alias. This is also problematic, because older versions of IE won't render rules for custom HTML tags, like "large."

3. Using JavaScript.

Apply no CSS rules to the custom tags, and use JS to generate them. Of course, JavaScript doesn't have universal support, but older browsers should still handle it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend do class .h1.
large will only looks like h1.

```css
.h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.67em;
    margin-bottom: 0.67em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<large class="h1"> AAA </large>
<h1>AAA</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

In CSS:

```
.stop-p-lf p { display: inline; }
```

Then in HTML:

```
<div class="stop-p-lf"><p>This will be inline</p></div><p>And this don't</p>
```